# Выдвижное меню

Tags: php, html, javascript

Подскажите статейку или хоть что-то искал, но всё, что находил, - это меню с разделами. О чём я говорю.

[image]

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: региться на форуме ради того, чтобы посмотреть картинку из вопроса? не, не охота

Comment: ну я просто не знаю как это обеснить

Comment: @bukvo278, я о том, что картинку не видно - залейте куда-то

Comment: готово   ))

Comment: Отвратный русский язык и желание получить всё, не зная даже самых простейших основ CSS/HTML - гнев, ненависть - вот мои чувства.

Comment: @bukvo278 Вопрос удаляется за несоответствие требованиям по качеству, предъявляемым к темам на форуме. Как минимум: 1) безграмотная речь, 2) отсутствие попыток самостоятельного решения, 3) заливка изображений на сторонний ресурс, требующий регистрации. И т.п.

Не рекомендуем восстанавливать удаляемые вопросы, это неминуем приведет к блокировке учетной записи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то [так](http://jsfiddle.net/th3XW/).

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

и

```
.menu {
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    -moz-transition: left 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: left 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: left 1s ease-out;
    transition: left 1s ease-out;
    position: absolute;
    left: -140px;
}

.menu:hover {
  left: 0px;

}
```

Comment: спс а куды это девать 
.menu {
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    -moz-transition: left 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: left 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: left 1s ease-out;
    transition: left 1s ease-out;
    position: absolute;
    left: -140px;
}

.menu:hover {
  left: 0px;

}

Comment: А как сделать больше и цвет чёрный спс

Comment: Я не могу найти как в CSS поменять цвет текста всё что я нахажу не робит

Comment: Я посмотрел, так как я очень плохо знаю CSS, я решил сделать через html и просто поставил `<p style="color:#FFFFFF">`.

Comment: @Deonis анимация супер, надо взять на заметку :)